# Does anyone have experience with migrating a MS Dynamics database to CiviCRM

Tags: migration

We are in touch with an organization that is planning a move to CiviCRM. They currently use Microsoft Dynamics and they will want to migrate the data into CiviCRM (I suspect 4.6). Anyone done that before, hints, pitfalls, approaches, experiences they would like to share?

Comment: Did you get any help?

Comment: No answer yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

We are just at the end of migrating an organisation who were using MS Dynamics. In this case, they were providing us with spreadsheets and we were then sorting out the data clean up and manipulation in order to get the results required in CiviCRM.

We didn't use our more complex tools such as the Drupal Migrate approach that we developed for a number of reasons, but even without that we have for example managed to take the old 'one row for every year of membership' and import it so we have a single row for continuous memberships etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this with MS Dynamics. But I did it from QuickBooks. We exported Excel reports out for Contacts and Donation history. Then we imported them into Civi. I'm sure you can do it that way without to much trouble.

We found the API csv Import Extension very useful for getting our information imported.